# What happens when a question with a bounty is migrated?

Tags: support, migration, bounty

I asked a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172886/mixing-properties-of-random-walks-on-graphs) a few days ago which has received no responses (comments or answers) in spite of the fact that I put a 150 point bounty on it yesterday.  It is quite possible that it just hasn't caught the right person's attention yet and so I'm going to leave it for another couple days, but I'm starting to suspect that it will get more attention at cstheory.stackexchange.

My question is: if a moderator were to migrate the question, what would happen to the bounty?  If the bounty transfers then it would create a means for transferring points in bulk from one forum to another, and it seems unlikely that the system would be designed this way.  But if the bounty vanishes then it would make more sense to wait out the bounty period before migrating.  Does anybody know what will happen?

Comment: Is a question with active bounty eligible at all for closure / migration? -- At least a user cannot vote to close in such situation, as far as I know.

Comment: See also [What happens to a bounty question if it gets migrated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38819/what-happens-to-a-bounty-question-if-it-gets-migrated) on meta.SE.

Answer (score 5):

Moderators can cancel and thereby refund a bounty (only to be done under special circumstances). If you flag and ask for migration they might agree to first cancel the bounty and then migrate it.

As mentioned in a comment a question with a bounty cannot be closed (and thus also not migrated); this restriction also is present for moderators.

As sources see for the cancel mechanism [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103) and also as part of the MSE FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: That seems to make sense.  I will flag the question for a moderator and explain my request - thanks for your help.